# Как запаковать файлы без вложенности в директорию?

Tags: linux, terminal, zip, tar

Имеются файлы:

```
/dirname/file.sh
         file1.php
         file2.png
         scripts/file.js
```

При добавление в архив:

```
zip dirname.zip dirname/*
```

В архиве файлы содержатся в папке `dirname`.

```
dirname.zip/dirname/file.sh ....
```

Нужно:

```
dirname.zip/file.sh ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй добавить `-C` после команды :

```
zip -C dirname.zip dirname/*
```

---

корректировка из комментария:

зайди внутрь самой папки, которую нужно запаковать, затем запакуй рекурсивно все файлы в ней, и сохрани на директорию выше:

```
zip -r ../dirname.zip *
```

Comment: zip error: Invalid command arguments (short option 'C' not supported)

Comment: Перепутал с tar коммандой. Тогда зайди внутрь самой папки которую нужно запаковать затем запакуй рекурсивно все файлы в ней и сохрани на директорию выше zip -r ../dirname.zip *

Comment: Как вариант годится